# Convert gnome-help (yelp) xml to static html with xslt

Tags: html, xml, linux, xslt, gnome

Some of the gnome applications on linux use a help browser called `yelp`.  For example, the gnome-calculator, `gcalctool`, has its help files located in `/usr/share/gnome/help/gcalctool`

The folders there are then sorted by language.  These help files essentially consist of an xml file and some accompanying png figures.

What I'm trying to do is convert this xml and its accompanying png figures into static HTML because I want to be able to properly view and navigate the document from a different browser (firefox). If you want to see what I'm talking about and you are on Linux, just run `gcalctool` and open the help menu.

Unfortunately, opening the xml directly with firefox is not successful because there are no stylesheets and thus firefox doesn't know how to format it.  I have read that gnome applications make use of a library called `libxslt` (http://xmlsoft.org/libxslt/) for applying stylesheets.  I am not familiar with xslt at all.  Are the stylesheets saved elsewhere, or embedded in the source when it is compiled?

I guess what I'm wondering is if it's possible to somehow use libxslt by itself or another tool to convert the xml and figures into static HTML, preferably in the same manner yelp does this when it executes, or in a manner that results in an exact/very similar output to what yelp displays.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

gcalctool uses [docbook](http://www.docbook.org/). Yelp brings everything to display this xml format. You will find some projects to convert this docbook document to html on http://wiki.docbook.org/DocBookToXhtml.

best regards
Majo

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how old your gcalctool is, its help files might be in DocBook or Mallard. If it's Mallard, you'll see a bunch of `.page` files. Otherwise, it's DocBook. Either way, you can use `yelp-build` to create HTML files. It's part of the `yelp-tools` package, and uses the same transformations as Yelp. For DocBook, pass the top-level XML file:

```
yelp-build html -o /path/for/output/ /path/to/gcalctool.xml
```

For Mallard, pass the directory containing the `.page` files:

```
yelp-build html -o /path/for/output/ /path/to/gcalctool/
```

`yelp-build` will build the HTML, copy the images and other media files, and take care of the CSS and JavaScript.